# Click-to-Edit text field with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on Vue js and having an issue editing a field. When I click on a field to edit it, *all* the editable fields become active. Here is my code.

```js
 export default {
        props: ['profileHeight'],

        data() {
            return {
                User: User,
                isEditing: false,
                form:{
                    name:'',
                    email: '',
                },
            };
        },

        mounted() {
        },

        methods: {
            activateInEditMode() {
                this.isEditing = true
            },
            deActivateInEditMode() {
                this.isEditing = false
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
 <span>Profile settings</span>
                        <p>Full name<span v-on:click="activateInEditMode" v-show="!isEditing">{{User.state.auth.name}}</span>
                            <span v-show="isEditing" >
                             <input v-model="form.name" type="text" class="form-control" >
                            </span>
                        </p>

                        <p>E-mail<span>{{User.state.auth.email}}</span>
                            <span v-show="isEditing" >
                             <input v-model="form.email" type="text" class="form-control" >
                            </span>
                        </p>
```

[image]

Comment: You used same `v-model="form.name"` for both!! Change it to different!

Comment: Also take `form:{
                    name:'', email: ''
                }` in `data()` Your problem solved!:)

Comment: @HirenGohel not really, because it checks `isEditing` variable and shows all the fields.

Comment: Ok, but you need to define this for edit! I know issue not solved with define this!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using focus and blur methods to show/hide form elements!
Hope this helps!

```js
                            
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      user : {
        name: '',
        email: ''
      },
      editField : ''
    }
  },
  methods : {
    focusField(name){
      this.editField = name;
    },
    blurField(){
      this.editField = '';
    },
    showField(name){
      return (this.user[name] == '' || this.editField == name)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Profile settings</h1>
  <label for="user-name">Full name</label>
  <div class="field">
    <span class="field-value" v-show="!showField('name')" @click="focusField('name')">{{user.name}}</span>
    <input v-model="user.name" v-show="showField('name')" id="user-name" type="text" class="field-value form-control" @focus="focusField('name')" @blur="blurField">
  </div>
  
  <label for="user-email">Email address</label>
  <div class="field">
    <span class="field-value" v-show="!showField('email')" @click="focusField('email')">{{user.email}}</span>
    <input v-model="user.email" v-show="showField('email')" type="email" class="field-value form-control" @focus="focusField('email')" @blur="blurField">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looking for an optimum solution so that I don't need to create computed properties, form may have 10 fields so I need to create 10 computed properties?

Comment: You can define method instead. 
Take a look to edited example

Comment: If we don't make any changes to the text, it doesn't get closed on blur

Answer (score 13):

There are are dozens of ways to do this. I might recommend a component.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("editable",{
  props:["label", "value"],
  template:`
  <p>
    {{label}} 
    <span @click="editing=true" v-show="!editing">
      {{value}}
    </span>
    <span v-show="editing" >
      <input :value="value"
             @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
             @keydown.enter="editing=false"
             type="text" 
             class="form-control" >
    </span>
  </p>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      editing: false,
    }
  }
})

const User = {
  name: 'bob',
  email: 'bob@example.com'
}

new Vue({
  el:"#app",

  data() {
    return {
      form: User
    };
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>Profile settings</span>
  <editable label="Full name" v-model="form.name"></editable>
  <editable label="E-mail" v-model="form.email"></editable>
  <br>
  {{form}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I have written a component for this, I call it `Click-to-Edit`.

What it does:

- Supports `v-model`
- Saves changes on clicking elsewhere and on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**ClickToEdit.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text"
           v-if="edit"
           :value="valueLocal"
           @blur.native="valueLocal = $event.target.value; edit = false; $emit('input', valueLocal);"
           @keyup.enter.native="valueLocal = $event.target.value; edit = false; $emit('input', valueLocal);"
           v-focus=""
             />
        <p v-else="" @click="edit = true;">
          {{valueLocal}}
        </p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

  props: ['value'],

  data () {
  return {
      edit: false,
      valueLocal: this.value
    }
  },

  watch: {
    value: function() {
      this.valueLocal = this.value;
    }
  },

  directives: {
    focus: {
      inserted (el) {
        el.focus()
      }
    }
  }

}
</script>
```